# Post to named Facebook page?

Tags: ios, facebook

I can currently read the newsfeed from `http://facebook.com/RelayForLife`, however I don't know how to post to this page (or other similar named pages that allow posting) as the logged in user. All examples I see out there are for posting to the user's page or an app page.

Obviously, I can't use the built-in SLComposeViewController to accomplish this.

Comment: You're going to have to use the facebook Graph API, check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph

Comment: I don't think you are able to post to a page.. only a persons profile.

Answer (score 0):

you can only post to facebook page if user (Profile posting), using graph api and facebooksdk. You need to get user first to like that page then you can post to that page